# Titanium: [ERROR] : Must set a connection to OPENED before send()

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to download multiple files, but for some reason, it only downloads one file.

My code:

```
for (var fl = 0; fl < fileurls.length; fl++){
    var fname = fileurls[fl].substr(fileurls[fl].lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fname);

    if(file.exists()) {  
        dlurls.push(fname);
        Ti.API.info('File exists, adding: ' + fname)
    }

    if(!file.exists()) {  
        Ti.API.info('File does not exist, downloading: ' + fname)
        modalview.show();
        ind.show();
        c.open('GET',fileurls[fl]);
        ind.message = 'Downloading: ' + fname;
        c.file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, fname);
        c.onload = function(e)
        {
            dlurls.push(fname);
        };
        c.send();
    } 

    Ti.API.info('Total files: ' + fileurls.length + ' Downloaded files: ' + dlurls.length)
    if (fileurls.length==dlurls.length){
        modalview.hide();
        ind.hide();
    }
}
```

So the for loop parses the json, and finds all the photos that need to be downloaded. 
It checks the file system to see if they exist in which case it pushes the filename to the downloaded files list. If the file does not exist, it initiates a download which when complete pushes the file to the downloaded file list. 
When done if filelist is equal to downloaded file list, means all files are there.

So, it does loop through all the files, but only one download is initiated?

```
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: IMG_1643_result.JPG
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: IMG_3883_result.JPG
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: 32103.JPG
[ERROR] :  Must set a connection to OPENED before send()
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: 32142.JPG
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: kale02.JPG
[ERROR] :  Must set a connection to OPENED before send()
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: 3213212.JPG
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: 32123.JPG
[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 0
[INFO] :   File does not exist, downloading: 32132.jpg
[ERROR] :  Must set a connection to OPENED before send()
...

[INFO] :   Total files: 27 Downloaded files: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 0.602950394153595
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1.6029504537582397
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1.1585098505020142
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 2.1585099697113037
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 2.2008988857269287
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 3.8818702697753906
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 4.881870269775391
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 1
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 2.251030445098877
[INFO] :   ONDATASTREAM1 - PROGRESS: 3.251030445098877
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what i did is i put the entire request in a function, and then had the oncomplete call call the function. Now it works.